# Accesoire development, determine publish page

Tags: add-on-development

An older accesoire add-on i have have, uses
`if($this->EE->input->get('C') == 'content_publish'){ ... }`
to determine if we're on the publish page.

Since 2.8/2.9 the cp url structure changed
`example.com/system/index.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form&channel_id=3&S=x`

1. Could check the uri class segments
2. Could check EE->router->class and ->method

What are current/good methods to determine control panel pages we're on?

Answer (score 4):

`ee()->router->fetch_class()` and `ee()->router->fetch_method()` should always reveal that information to you, regardless of the URL pattern or special routing.